# inOrder traversal works but keeps printing None at the end

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary-search-tree

My inOrder traversal code works except it prints None at the very end after all the values have been printed. Can someone tell me why? Thanks!

```
def inOrder(self):
    if self:
        if self.left:
            self.left.inOrder()
        print(self.value)
        if self.right:
            self.right.inOrder()
```

Comment: Are you doing `print(something.inOrder())` instead of `something.inOrder()`?

Comment: That was it! haha, I feel dumb. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are doing something like `print(something.inOrder())` instead of `something.inOrder()`